# How R-Trees, R*-Trees can be used to index the Road Network?

Tags: spatial-join, indexing, rtree

I am trying to understand the Tree Indexing method of the Road network. In R-Tree the Minimum Bounding Rectangle is used to store the data points, but how it can hold the line segments of the Map? Or each MBR will just hold the single edge of the roadmap? From a basic Spatial Join what I got is that the connected line segment's rectangle overlaps.
Still it seems a lot of confusing to me. Could anybody please help me with the simple yet easy explanation. A graphical visualization would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary R-Trees in GIS do not consider the topology/connections of the edges in sense of graph theory.

The MBR of each feature is considered in the R-Tree on its own, depending only on its spatial position, not on connections to any other road segments.

Comment: You mean the X and Y location co-ordinates? e.g. from a large datasets of a city containing like about 25000 nodes and it's longitude and latitude coordinates, and if we manage to depict them into a 2-D graph so that all the nodes will fit inside of the graph, and we make a leaves size of 16-nodes per child node, then can we just draw a box and put every 16 nodes in that MBR-box till the last existing nod. Then again putting those boxes into big boxes and so on until we make a big Box of the root node, is that how trees formed from those nodes? Correct me if I'm wrong.